# can't set ng model on checkbox inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a row of checkboxes, only one can be checked at a time, and if you click on the checkbox that is checked, its state should flip. So if it is checked and you click it, it should uncheck, and vice versa.

**model**

```
this.models = [
  {name: 'blah', defaulted: false},
  {name: 'fdsf', defaulted: false},
  ...
]
```

**template**

```
<input 
  type="checkbox"
  ng-repeat="model in vm.models"
  ng-checked="model.defaulted === true" 
  ng-change="vm.setDefault($index)"
  ng-model="model.defaulted" />
```

**a.** this one doesn't work, model isn't updated

http://embed.plnkr.co/O275a9O7y60NuimFYdYi?show=preview

```
this.setDefault = (j) => this.models = this.models.map((m, i) => {
  return j === i 
    ? Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: !m.defaulted}) 
    : Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: false}) 
})
```

**b.** model updates correctly in this one but you are unable to untoggle a checkbox by clicking on it again (hence the `!m.defaulted` in example a)

http://embed.plnkr.co/MOBuN06R0hmcnpGu01Z7?show=preview

```
// this works, but now you can't uncheck a box that is checked
this.setDefault = (j) => this.models = this.models.map((m, i) => {
  return j === i 
    ? Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: true}) 
    : Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: false}) 
})
```

Need a solution without using radios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to change:

```
this.setDefault = (j) => this.models = this.models.map((m, i) => {
  return j === i 
    ? Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: true}) 
    : Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: false}) 
})
```

To

```
this.setDefault = (j) => this.models = this.models.map((m, i) => {
  return j === i 
    ? Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: m.defaulted}) 
    : Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: false}) 
})
```

By changing it to `Object.assign({}, m, {defaulted: m.defaulted})` you allow to toggle the state of the current selected/unselected checkbox.

**Edit**: Please note that @PankajParkar's answer is better, because unlike my answer, that simply solve the main issue, that answer is also  better for performances as it doesn't overwrite the `this.models` array using `Array.prototype.map()` - Which makes angular re-render the view in the `ngRepeat` loop.

You're welcome to accept their answer instead

Comment: ah right, because i guess ng-model worked its magic before the method got called...nice catch.

Comment: @DanielLizik I believe that's the reason: _Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input. The expression is evaluated **immediately**, **unlike the JavaScript onchange** event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the user leaves the form element or presses the return key)._ [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the way you played with `index` of an array element. It will not work if you apply any filtering over `models` collection. Rather I'd suggest you to pass current selected model to `setDefault` function like below and make current model flag `true`, other will be set to `false`.
Also there is no need to use `Object.assign` to everytime create a new copy of an object. Rather looping and modifying the existing array element makes more sense.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
  ng-change="vm.setDefault(model)"
  ng-model="model.defaulted" />
```

**Code**

```
this.setDefault = (j) => {
    this.models.forEach(i => i.defaulted = i.defaulted && j.name === i.name);
}
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/L9hrAb4WPjZl5AcMuxhR?p=preview)

Comment: i tried that but it wasnt actually updating the model, only the view

Comment: @DanielLizik please check answer now, I was on wrong track when I answered it initally.

Comment: @PankajParkar I think that the main issue is that your code doesn't solve the scenario where the checkbox is already checked, it will keep it checked instead of unchecking it (That's why the OP is using checkboxes instead of radio buttons)

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks for heads up. I wasn't aware of that case. Now I fixed it. Please have a look at it and let me know, if it is fine now? Sorry to say. I personally don't like the concept of using `Object.assign` here..

Comment: Personally I think that this should be the accepted answer because your solution doesn't overwrite the `models` array each time with `Array.prototype.map()`, which is better for performances - If the OP see this, I don't mind if they do so

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input name="foo" ng-change="vm.setDefault(opt)" ng-model="opt.defaulted" type="checkbox" ng-repeat="opt in vm.models" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
this.setDefault = function(opt) {
    this.models.forEach((val) => {
        if(opt != val) {
            val.defaulted = false;
        }
    });
};
```

Collected some downvotes, but it actually works pretty well.

https://plnkr.co/edit/BhE7XF?p=preview

Comment: Consider removing `ng-checked` which shouldn't be used with `ng-model` all together..

Answer (score 0):

I said screw it and used icons instead of checkboxes

```
<i
  ng-click="vm.setDefault($index)"
  ng-class="{'fa-circle-thin': model.defaulted === false, 'fa-circle': model.defaulted === true}"
  class="fa">
</i>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/5dj865ew1dqUMM9cchrY?p=preview